# Why is uppercase not sorted correctly here?

Tags: java, sorting, alphabetical

I am attempting to sort a `List<String>` of items. Here's the unsorted `List`, and how it's currently being sorted:

```
Unsorted: [Pineapple, pineapple, apple, apricot, Banana, mango, Mango, melon, peach]
Sorted: [apple, apricot, Banana, mango, Mango, melon, peach, Pineapple, pineapple]
```

How come `Mango` is not placed before `mango`, and why is `Pineapple` before `pineapple`?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        List<String> fruits = new ArrayList<String>(7);

        fruits.add("Pineapple");
        fruits.add("pineapple");
        fruits.add("apple");
        fruits.add("apricot");
        fruits.add("Banana");
        fruits.add("mango");
        fruits.add("Mango");
        fruits.add("melon");        
        fruits.add("peach");

        System.out.println("Unsorted: " + fruits);

        Collections.sort(fruits, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {              
                return o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2);
            }
        });

        System.out.println("Sorted: " + fruits);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you are using a compare that ignores case.

Comment: I have rolled back to revision 1 because revision 2 presented the unexpected output as being the desired result.

Comment: @admdrew: Would you please stop editing the question in a manner that clearly changes its meaning (and makes an already confusing situation worse).

Comment: @NPE My apologies, my initial edit was indeed wrong. I changed the wording to reflect actual vs expected output.

Answer (score 5):

You used `compareToIgnoreCase()` as your comparison method, so it compared 'Pineapple' and 'pineapple' as 0 (same string), leaving them in the order they were found in when sorting since Collections.sort guarantees that equal elements won't be reordered.
In other words, 'Pineapple' came before 'pineapple', so now that they're equal strings due to the ignoreCase, 'Pineapple' will stay in front of 'pineapple'.

Since the unsorted list has 'Pineapple' before 'pineapple', the comparison put them into the sorted list in that same order. These same rules applied for 'Mango' and 'mango'. The comparison method you're looking for is just `compareTo()` which does take upper case and lower case letters into account.

Comment: My understanding of the OP's requirements is that the expected result is `apple, apricot, Banana, Mango, mango, melon, peach, Pineapple, pineapple`. This doesn't do that, so either this answer is wrong or my interpretation of the question is wrong.

Comment: Are you sure? To my understanding, we know what the unsorted list is. Then the list is sorted with the Collections.sort method but the comparison function is overridden to sort by ignoring case. On top of this. Collections.sort is stable, so it's guaranteed to not reorder equal elements. Thus, the expected result is not possible because the comparison function overload changed 'Mango' and 'mango' to be seen as equal elements, and thus they maintain their same order as the unsorted list.

Comment: Whether on not it's possible (it certainly is BTW) should not affect the interpretation of the question. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> How come 'Mango' is not placed before 'mango' and why is 'Pineapple' before 'pineapple'?

According to your comparator, "Mango" and "mango" compare equal. Since [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) is [stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability), items that compare equal are returned in the order in which they were found in the original collection (an *unstable* sort would return them in an arbitrary order).

If you expect "Mango" to always be returned just before "mango", your comparator needs to reflect that. This means that "Mango" needs to compare *less than* "mango" (but *greater than* "apple", "apricot", "Banana" etc).

One way to achieve this is with the following comparator:

```
Collections.sort(fruits, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {              
        int ret = o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2);
        if (ret == 0) {
            ret = o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
        return ret;
    }
});
```

This would return:

```
Sorted: [apple, apricot, Banana, Mango, mango, melon, peach, Pineapple, pineapple]
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using `compareToIgnoreCase`, which as the name says ignore the case while comparing two String. So, mango and Mango are the same, and left out in the same order as they were in (the sort is *stable*, eg: equals element are left in the order they were before sorting.).

On a side note, you comparator is the same as [String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER). `compareToIgnoreCase` simplies call that comparator.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) `Collections.sort` is guaranteed to be *stable* - the relative ordering of items that compare as equal does not change as a result of the sorting.  If you want to enforce an ordering that puts upper case letters ahead of their lower case equivalents then you need to use a different comparator that implements that ordering, the simplest way to implement that would probably be to use a `java.text.RuleBasedCollator`.

Answer (score -2):

You're doing everything correctly.

"mango" should indeed come before "pineapple" and after "apple".

But "pineapple" and "Pineapple" are "the same".  Equal.  "0".  Because you said "ignoreCase".

Comment: That doesn't answer the OP's question.